# Set whole byte if first bit is 1

Tags: c, bit, bit-shift

I'm trying to make program that will for for example `273(000100010001b)` make to `4095(111111111111b)`.

Funny part is that my program works for first 2 iterations, for example `17(00010001b)` correctly returns `255(11111111b)` but every byte after that doesn't work. For instance `273(000100010001b)` returns `61951(1111000111111111b)` and I cant figure out why is that.

Here is my code

```
int x,temp, i;
int mask = 15;
scanf_s("%d", &x);
temp = x;
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    mask<<=i*4;
    if((temp&1)==1){
        x|=mask;
    } else{

    }
    temp>>=4;
    }
printf("%d", x);
```

Comment: `mask <<= i*4` --> `mask <<= 4`

Comment: The "first" bit of a byte is the least significant, then?

Comment: Try something like `(1 - (x & 1)) - 1`.

Comment: @user3386109 Still doesn't work as expected, when i enter 273 it returns 65521 (1111 1111 1111 0001b)

Comment: @user3386109 I don't think I quite understand you, I already have `temp>>=4` at the end of for body

Comment: Move `mask <<= 4` to the bottom.

Comment: "Set whole byte if first bit is 1" is amiss.  Do you mean "Set whole nibble if first bit is 1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the shift you perform on `mask`. You shift it by 0 on the 1st iteration, 4 on the 2nd, 12 (4 + 8) on the 3rd and so on.

Also, you don't apply the mask over all the bits of `temp`. I can't tell if you do this on purpose.

Here you are a fixed version:

```c
int foo(int x) {
/*  ^ I didn't know how to call such function */
    static size_t const mask_size = 4;
    unsigned mask = 15;

    int temp = x;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)) / mask_size; ++i) {
        if ((temp & 1) == 1) {
            x |= mask;
        }
        mask <<= mask_size;
        temp >>= mask_size;
    }

    return x;
}
```

My results are:

```
in:  17(10) = 10001(2)
out: 255(10) = 11111111(2)
in:  273(10) = 100010001(2)
out: 4095(10) = 111111111111(2)
in:  4369(10) = 1000100010001(2)
out: 65535(10) = 1111111111111111(2)
```